# Undefined offset on comparing elements in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm trying to compare the dates of 2 elements using a foreach loop. Whenever they match add them to an array and push that array into another one.

The idea for this is that I'll show them all in a table, matching element-dates will have their date column grouped (colspan=n). Using a secondary array I'll be able to use the length of that array as colspan amount.

```
$elements = array();
$ts_index = 0;

foreach($timesheetweeks as $timesheetweek){
    $arr = array();
    foreach($timesheetweek->timesheets as $index => $timesheet){

        $this_date = $timesheetweek->timesheets[$index]->start_date;
        $next_date = $timesheetweek->timesheets[$index + 1]->start_date;

        if($this_date == $next_date){
            $elements[$ts_index][] = $timesheetweek->timesheets[$index + 1];
        } else {
            $elements[$ts_index] = $timesheetweek->timesheets[$index];
            $ts_index += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly after some headaches and a lost match against Argentinia I get the following error:

> Undefined offset: 4

fyi: this is what I try to achieve:

```
elements [
    1 => element1, //diff date
    2 => array( //same date array
        element2,
        element3
    ),
    3 => element4 //diff date
]
```

Comment: because of your `$index + 1`. when it gets to the last element, it's still looking for the next one after that. You'd be better off using a for loop

Comment: @ElefantPhace: As I thought and replied to Orion, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure about some of the code but this general idea should help:

```
$elements = array();
$ts_index = -1;
$currentDate = '';    

foreach ($timesheetweeks as $timesheetweek) {

    foreach ($timesheetweek->timesheets as $index => $timesheet) {

      if ($timesheet->start_date != $currentDate) {

        // check to see if the last $elements element had just one entry, if so flatten it
        if ($ts_index > -1 && count($elements[$ts_index]) == 1) {
          $elements[$ts_index] = $elements[$ts_index][0];
        }

        $currentDate = $timesheet->start_date;
        $ts_index++;

        // create a new array to store this timesheet and any more that may have the same start_date
        $elements[$ts_index] = array();
      }

      $elements[$ts_index][] = $timesheet;

    }
}

// if the last element we added is an array with 1 item, flatten it
if ($ts_index > -1 && count($elements[$ts_index]) == 1) {
   $elements[$ts_index] = $elements[$ts_index][0];
}
```

Comment: Hey James, thanks for your reply. But I don't get the **$elements[$ts_index] = array();** part. This doesn't make quite sense to me. I edited my page to cover what I actually mean by the nested arrays.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  Because we're handling just the "current" timesheet in the loop, we don't know yet if there will be more than one with the same date later in the loop.  To be safe, we make each member of $elements[$ts_index] an array, and after we're done with the "current" start_date, we can check if there was only one element in that array and flatten it if so.

Comment: Unfortunatly this sets everything in the main array. I'm trying to debug at the moment to see where the fault is.

Comment: [Seems to work ok for me](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b56db2b4d49dedd0e76e8cf43e2b5ee5b6357175)

Comment: I am truly sorry, I just found out my mistake, it works now. I totally forgot that the date was actually a Carbon object. I simply had to call upon **->toDateTimeString()** and it worked... I'm so sorry ^^

Answer (score 0):

The item `$timesheetweek->timesheets[$index + 1]` does not exist when `$index` reaches its maximium value `$index = count($timesheetweek->timesheets) -1;`.

Comment: Aah so it's an outofbounds error :D That makes sense. But how do I implement this check? It's really not my day right now. So I suppose using **$index = count($timesheetweek->timesheets) -1;** as you suggested and put the if/else closure in between?

Comment: You can add a condition to make sure that this item exists. For example `if($index < count($timesheetweek->timesheets) - 1)`.